# Sorting Twitter data in Excel based on index number

Tags: r, excel, twitter

**Problem:**

I am working on my thesis, and I must say I am pretty new to the more advanced stuff from Excel, and I never used R before. What I did was the following: I used R to connect with Twitter, and I searched and saved Tweets based on a certain keyword. Right now I want to make sure my data is sorted properly so I can perform analyses on it. However, I can't seem to get my data fixed right, nor with R (cause it's not reading the data), nor with Excel. Currently my data looks like this:

**Data example:**

```
,"text","favorited","favoriteCount","replyToSN","created","truncated","replyToSID","id","replyToUID","statusSource","screenName","retweetCount","isRetweet","retweeted","longitude","latitude"                                      
1,"RT @cdavandaag: De hashtag #ikstemCDA is deze maand al 7.500 (!) keer gebruikt, fantastisch. Op naar een mooi uitslag. #CDA #PS15 http://t.…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:58:23,FALSE,NA,"577982342775615488",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Cecile2511",25,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA                                      
2,"RT @Matthijs85: Ligt het trouwens aan mij                                        
of wordt verschil CDA/VVD nu heel groot uitgelicht, terwijl ze feitelijk 92% hetzelfde stemmen?                                     
    #…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:58:04,FALSE,NA,"577982262282698752",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","meneerharmsen",3,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA                                     
3,"@PuckPetrus bang makerij bemoei je niet met je buurman les 1                                     
wil jij de les gelezen worden ?                                     
    #vvd #pvda #d66 #cda",FALSE,0,"PuckPetrus",2015-03-17 23:57:39,FALSE,"577980323885105152","577982156426899458","1378104055","<a href=""http://twitter.com"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter Web Client</a>","pufpufpafpaf",0,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA                                     
4,"RT @FrankScholman: Het #CDA kiest #LagereLasten! Hier hebben we 7 goede redenen voor: http://t.co/utQt0LfEzl. #NOSdebat #PS15 #MeerBanen ht…",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:57:36,FALSE,NA,"577982146582806528",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","gijsdupont",4,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA                                       
5,"RT @Jan_Slagter: In Hilversum werden de Buma awards uitgereikt, en  Buma wint het #nosdebat #cda",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:56:36,FALSE,NA,"577981895570546688",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","Ztrmarco",38,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA                                        
6,"RT @StSteenbakkers: Peiling Maurice de Hond: tweestrijd VVD en CDA! Stem CDA!!! #Lagerelasten #CDA #100pBrabant",FALSE,0,NA,2015-03-17 23:56:31,FALSE,NA,"577981871168090113",NA,"<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone</a>","gijsdupont",5,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA
```

And so on. When I convert text to columns in excel the output is this:

```
    text    favorited   created id  statusSource    screenName  retweetCount    isRetweet   retweeted                                                                       
1   RT @cdavandaag: De hashtag #ikstemCDA is deze maand al 7.500 (!) keer gebruikt, fantastisch. Op naar een mooi uitslag. #CDA #PS15 http://t.…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:58 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  Cecile2511  25  TRUE    FALSE                                                                       
2   RT @Matthijs85: Ligt het trouwens aan mij                                                                                                       
    #…" FALSE   0   FALSE   NA  meneerharmsen   3   TRUE    FALSE   NA                                                                      
    #vvd #pvda #d66 #cda"   FALSE   0   FALSE   1378104055  pufpufpafpaf    0   FALSE   FALSE   NA                                                                      
4   RT @FrankScholman: Het #CDA kiest #LagereLasten! Hier hebben we 7 goede redenen voor: http://t.co/utQt0LfEzl. #NOSdebat #PS15 #MeerBanen ht…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:57 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  gijsdupont  4   TRUE    FALSE
```

**Conclusion:**

The programs are not reading the Tweets properly. Since I have a huge amount of Tweets, manually cleaning it is not an option. I thought it might be possible to sort the Tweets based on the Indexnumber already present in the first column. Is there a way to do this (in excel)? So basically make it jump to the next row whenever it finds the next number? Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just stay within R for automatic cleaning? It would be best if you could provide a small reproducible example (incl. the code you used).

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. I tried to do it in R, but i can't get the data right. I think somehow it got mixed up with ; and ". Therefore the seperators don't work anymore properly. The code I used so far in R is this:

> cdadata <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\Eigenaar\\Dropbox\\Thesis\\Data\\R test cleaning\\Data CDA.csv", header=FALSE)

Comment: and to save the CSV I used SearchTwitter (filtered with since functions and so on) function. And then I did <- write.csv

Answer (score 1):

I was able to import your data using

```
x <- read.table("text.csv", header = TRUE, comment.char = "Ł", sep = ",")
```

The trick is to specify a non-default comment  character, as # clashes with the twitter hastag.

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ X            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ text         : Factor w/ 6 levels "@PuckPetrus bang makerij bemoei je niet met je buurman les 1                                     \nwil jij de les gelezen worde"| __truncated__,..: 2 5 1 3 4 6
 $ favorited    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ favoriteCount: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ replyToSN    : Factor w/ 1 level "PuckPetrus": NA NA 1 NA NA NA
 $ created      : Factor w/ 6 levels "2015-03-17 23:56:31",..: 6 5 4 3 2 1
 $ truncated    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ replyToSID   : num  NA NA 5.78e+17 NA NA ...
 $ id           : num  5.78e+17 5.78e+17 5.78e+17 5.78e+17 5.78e+17 ...
 $ replyToUID   : int  NA NA 1378104055 NA NA NA
 $ statusSource : Factor w/ 2 levels "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",..: 2 1 1 2 2 2
 $ screenName   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Cecile2511","gijsdupont",..: 1 3 4 2 5 2
 $ retweetCount : int  25 3 0 4 38 5
 $ isRetweet    : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 $ retweeted    : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ longitude    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA
 $ latitude     : Factor w/ 5 levels "NA    ","NA                                     ",..: 3 2 2 4 5 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. When I apply this to my CSV i get the following error: > x <- read.table("Data CDA.csv", header = TRUE, comment.char = "Ł", sep = ",")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements

Comment: @AnnedeGroot copy/paste your example data you provided into a new file and try importing that.

Comment: Its still not working. > x <- read.table("C:\\Users\\Eigenaar\\Dropbox\\Thesis\\Data\\R test cleaning\\Book1.csv", header = TRUE, comment.char = "Ł", sep = ",")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements

I tried to copy the entire data file and I also just copied the text above to book2. I also tried it with the excel output data. All (still) the same error. Just making sure: I am copying it to an excel book and saving it as CSV  (comma delimited) after. This is what you meant right?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it! Thank you all for the help. Copying the first column of the CSV data to notepad ++ does the trick. From there I was able to import it!

For some reason R kept reading the "Ł" as "L". Therefore it was cutting off the data there. using comment.char= " ", as code solves the problem. Thanks everyone!